# How to make a Node, Express, CSS3, HTML5, MongoDB, Socket.io application run at cordova?

Tags: mongodb, sockets, cordova, express

I have a node project where I used: Express, MongoDB, Javascript, CSS3, HTML5 and Socket.io. I can run the server in localhost without problems.
the structure of my application is:

|-- \app

|-- \api-- MongodbFiles.js (schemas)

|-- \node_modules-- ModulesOfTheApplication

|-- \public--\css--style.css--\js--javascript.js

|--\views--TheViewsFile.ejs

|--package.json

|--server.js

I need to make it works in a mobile app android, I have tried to test the application in a emulated android plataform with cordova, but I have no idea how to make this structure works, because in the cordova project have some folders and the "config.xml", is a different structure.
So, what must I do to run this application in cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what I needed. I hosted my application in the nodejitsu, and then I redirected the config.xml file (the attribute src of tag content) to the domain that nodejitsu made to my app. Now I can run the app as I wanted in cordova.